# How to set PyQt6 window title font to bold

Tags: python, pyqt6

I would like to set the title of my pyqt6 application to bold text. The font weight of the title doesn't change.

Below is my code.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont

app = QApplication([])

window = QMainWindow()
window.setWindowTitle("MyPyQt6 App")

font = QFont()
font.setBold(True)

window.setFont(font)
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Comment: The OS draws window decorations, including the title bar, so you cannot do this. There are two alternatives, but I would highly discourage both of them: use special UTF characters that *seem* bold (the user font might not support them, making the title completely unreadable) or create your own title bar (it would look very different from the OS ones, and it doesn't seem worth the effort for this reason).

Comment: Using special UTF characters would also make it impossible for screenreaders to read it to users.

Comment: @ethry You're completely right, I was adding that too but I forgot it while editing. That's an extremely important point that is too often forgotten: I really hate its usage in social media, as it's very inconsiderate, and I hope they'll stop that annoying habit sooner or later.